# How many ways to make groups of 2 of factors of a number? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, grouping, permutation, combinations

If suppose a number X = A1*A2*...*An, where A1, A2, .., An are factors of X.
In how many ways can we arrange factors these N factors parenthising 2 at a time?

suppose X has 5 factors as g,h,j,k
expression ghjk can be evaluated in 5 ways i.e (((gh)j)k) , (g(h(jk))) , (g((hj)k)) , ((g(hj))k) and ((gh)(jk))

so for input as
ghjk

output should be
5

How do I do this in C/C++?

given 1 < N < 34 ..

Comment: What do you want: output the number of possible combinations, or output all combinations ?

Comment: are you looking for the permutations? or the combinations?

Comment: I don't know if it will require permutation or combination. So I tagged both.

Comment: @Synxis : I need the NUMBER OF possible combinations

Comment: Are A1, A2, A3... all distinct, or can there be repeats?

Comment: I think your problem is with combinations only, not permutations. Also, the number is a formulae that can take only line of code (and that you are surely able to write). For the list of all combinations, see my answer. Please note that you have approx 212 trillion combinations possibles...

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant "X has 5 factors as g, h, j, k, i"  you only put 4 factors for X above.
It seems like you are looking for combinations of 2 elements in your set of 5.

Wouldn't this be a simple Combination of S choose K with no repetition:

n! / k!(n-k)!

where n is the number of elements in the set and k is the k-combination.

for you it would be subsets of 2 out of a set of 5: (n = 5, k = 2)

5! / 2!*(5-2)! = 5! / (2! * 3!) = 10

(g,h), (g,j), (g,k), (g,i)

(h,j), (h,k), (h,i)

(j,k), (j, i)

(k,i)

So there are really 10 possible combinations of 2 factors in a set of 5.

Comment: NO!
in ghijk, after suppose selecting (hi), you have option of choosing (g(hi)) or ((hi)j)!!

Comment: "NO! ...".  Please keep in mind we are trying to help you.  After reading the other answers I realized this is not what you were looking for... the answers that mention Catalan numbers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the order of the factors, a product of `n` factors can be parenthesised in `C(n-1)` ways, where `C(k)` is the `k`-th [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number),

```
C(k) = 1/(k+1) * \binom(2*k, k)
     = 1/(k+1) * (2k)!/(k!)²
```

Since a (full) parenthesising of a product of `n` factors is equivalent to building a binary tree with `n` leaves, that is also the number of different structures of binary trees with `n` leaves.

If changing the order of factors is allowed, you have to multiply that by the number of different orders of the factors, which is simply `n!` if there are no repeated factors, and

```
n!/(a_1! * ... * a_k!)
```

if there are `k` distinct factors with multiplicities `a_i` respectively.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Thats really the solution to my question. Thanx.

Comment: Which formula? The one for the Catalan numbers or for the number of different orders of the factors?

Comment: According to your reply, what I understood is that catalan number of N-1 will give me EXACTLY the solution to my problem, is that true?
that catalan formula is a bit unclear to me!

Comment: Yes, `C(n-1)` gives you exactly the number of different ways to fully parenthesise a product of `n` factors (for `n >= 1`). For `n >= 2`, there are `n-1` points where you can have the outermost multiplication. Then you get the recurrence `P(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} P(i)*P(n-i)`, since you can parenthesise the part `A_1, ... A_i` in `P(i)` ways, and the part `A_(i+1), ..., A_n` in `P(n-i)` ways. The Catalan numbers have the same recurrence (modulo the different indexing), and `P(1) = C(0) = 1`, so `P(k) = C(k-1)`. The given formula allows a more efficient computation than the recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) : Cn is the number of way to parenthesize an associative expression. It is also the number of possible full-binary trees with n+1 leaves (full binary tree = a tree where each node have exactly 2 children, or is a leave).

Thus, it is possible to [use recursion to generate all combinations](http://ideone.com/RauVM9):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> str_vector;

// Combine u and v, and add the result to w
// u and v contains all possible combinations with respectively m and n - m letters
// So w will contain combinations with n letters
void combine(str_vector& w, const str_vector& u, const str_vector& v)
{
    for(unsigned int t = 0; t < u.size(); t++)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            w.push_back("(" + u[t] + v[i] + ")");
}

// The function resolving our problem
// It output an array containing all possible combinations
// with n letters, starting with startLetter
str_vector problem(unsigned int n, char startLetter)
{
    if(n == 1)
        // Only one combination with one letter.
        // Array with 1 string which contains only one character
        return str_vector(1,std::string(1,startLetter));
    else
    {
        str_vector w;
        // Get all combinations for n-1 letters, and add them to w
        for(unsigned int t = 1; t < n; t++)
            combine(w, problem(t, startLetter), problem(n - t, startLetter + (char)t));
        return w;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Get all possible combinations with 4 letters
    const str_vector& r = problem(4,'a');

    // Print all solutions
    for(unsigned int t = 0; t < r.size(); t++)
        std::cout << r[t] << "\n";
}
```

This code is not the fastest nor the most optimized. However, I think it is very readable.

For the number of combinations, the formulae is:

[image: Catalan number]

This can be simplified in:

```
       (2n)!
Cn = ---------
     n!² (n+1)
```

Computing Cn gives you the number of combinations with n+1 identifiers. It does not gives you the solutions, though.

Comment: Hi! First of all thank you very much for your reply. Thank you for indtroducing me with catalan numbers. I didn't know about them. According to wiki, thats exactly solution to my problem.
But am sorry to say that am a beginner in c++. So I don't understand these vectors and all. 
a BIG THANX anyways :D

Comment: One more thing, according to wiki
-------------
Cn is the number of different ways n + 1 factors can be completely parenthesized (or the number of ways of associating n applications of a binary operator). For n = 3, for example, we have the following five different parenthesizations of four factors:

![Like these](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/f/9/0f95f511173c52ef07ab865ac7bc9b3f.png)
--------------------------

Just calculating this ![Formula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/5/2/f526579b240d6912f8e5ac2068448d98.png) for N-1 will give me the solution?

Comment: I edited my answer. Vectors are dynamic arrays in C++. There is a [tutorial here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm), you should read it. Let me know if you have some problem to understand the algorithm.